# How do I set an instance variable on an Eloquent model?

Tags: php, model, laravel, eloquent

How would I go about creating a dynamic instance variable on an Eloquent model in Laravel4?

For example, I'd like to access $user->full_name, which would be created by concatenating $user->first_name and $user->last_name, both of which are stored in the DB. This is incorrect, but something to the extent of:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

  public $full_name = $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a `getFullNameAttribute` [accessor method](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators):

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function getFullNameAttribute ()
    {
        return $this->attributes['first_name'] . ' ' . $this->attributes['last_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'd rather call a class property rather than a method. Is there a way to auto-call a method after the db data has been loaded in to the model?

Comment: According to the documentation, you should be able to do the following http://paste.laravel.com/QS4 to get the full_name property

Comment: @Bryant, the idea behind accessors is that you can call them as though they are simply properties of the model. In the example above, you'd simply have to do $model->full_name. See [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2517-L2526) for more info